# How to resolve "Failed to connect to device '127.0.0.1' using Universal Authentication"?

Tags: uwp

I keep getting this error everytime I try to deploy my UWP app to my local device.

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error       DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '127.0.0.1' using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings. COMException - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007274D) [0x8007274D]  Voip`

I have absolutely ZERO idea on how to resolve this, as it seems everyone else that has this issue is trying to connect to a remote device.

Comment: The second entry returned by Google when looking for 'Failed to connect to device '127.0.0.1' using Universal Authentication' and hosted by social.msdn.microsoft.com  may be related to the issue you are experimenting.

Comment: @Frant I already have Developer mode enabled on my device

Comment: @Scronz: I see. The good point is that you are not alone, since at least another person encountered this issue while connecting to a non-remote device.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I got the same error.
The problem disappeared when I changed the platform to x86 (or x64) in Visual Studio's configuration manager.

[image]

Comment: That fix doesn't appear to work at least in my case. Downloaded a sample kit from Microsoft and out of the box will not run due to this same error.

Comment: OK. So for anyone else stumbling across this like I did - the confusion here is after reading the error, it instructs you to change the authentication in the Debug Properties menu. Interestingly, if you switch the Platform target in that configuration menu, it still wont work. You MUST change it from the ribbon menu, as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device is connected to your machine.

I had forgotten to plug in my device (hololens 2 in this case).

Solved this error straightaway. It's hard to find something thats not there. :D

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to deploy to HoloLens2 using USB.

I fixed it by going to `Settings > Update & Security > For developers` on the HoloLens and enabling `Use developer features`, `Device discovery`, and `Device portal`.

Answer (score 0):

personal experience

if you encounter an issue connecting to the remote device if the normal steps of unblocking do not work like restarting vs, run it as administrator, or miss config => do the following:
Reset all pairings in the device portal or on Xbox dev home
If you are using vs 2017, install vs 2022 choose UWP template for c# xaml Xbox
Make sure you tick the latest Windows SDK during for install when you are in vs 2022 installation process,
Re-pair should be re-enabled on the first deployment, even if it results in error when you deploy remotely it is okay cos the template is XAML and we are using .js
Then go back to vs 2017
For the target version keep as previous, but if an error is prompted choose the latest Windows SDK version
Redeploy to the remote machine again (wishing you luck, here I have prayed)
optional
8. If an error for the splash screen image is prompted, make sure you comment the code for the splash screen tag in AppManifest.xml, which is located in the project directory under debug > x64
Redeploy again
Happy debugging